# Configure Rails logger to swallow exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

Last night the cloud-gods set our disk to read-only for about two hours, and our Rails application went down because of errors writing to `app/production.log`.

Is there any way to configure or otherwise duck punch the Rails logger to swallow such exceptions in the future?

I'd rather serve requests without logging them than throw errors and serve nothing.

Comment: if not for logger your app would work from read-only disk? That's something

Comment: Often the database is on a separate system so it would work fine.

Comment: I'm curious how this relates to Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [this](http://www.juretta.com/log/2005/12/31/ruby_remote_logging/), or use it to write your own logger (or even a noop one), make an instance, and assign it to `Rails.logger`.

Comment: Writing my own subclass of the default Rails logger that swallows this exception works fine, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just kill logging without having to patch the app, you might have luck with this:

```
ln -s /dev/null log/production.log
```

That should pretty much end all logging by pitching it in the bit bucket.